# Can we write a readonly property in Groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy

I get an error `Cannot set the value of read-only property 'xxx'` in Groovy. Is there any solution to  write the **readonly** property like reflect or hook,could you show me the code?
My code is like this

```
void handlePackage(PackageApplication pack) {

  Set<File> jars = new HashSet<File>(pack.javaResourceFiles)
  pack.javaResourceFiles = jars
  jars.add(file('plugin.jar'))
}
```

Comment: Do you have a small example, and what you've tried?

Comment: I am write android grade script. And I try to modify the property '"javaResourceFiles"  of PackageApplication class,But there is an error said "Cannot set the value of read-only property 'javaResourceFiles' "

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste in the code you're trying?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing this? Feels like something that should be done in the gradle script itself as configuration, not in whatever that code is from?

Comment: I'd like to add my plugin jar to PackageApplication task, PackageApplication is a task in android gradle plugin.